# Find arrayelement and return associated value

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

I have an array that is created dynamically depending on different parameters. Its items can be (e.g.) `Item(0) = Colorado` or `Item(0) = Arkansas, Item(1) = Utah` or `Item(0) = Utah, Item(1) = Colorado, Item(2) = Arkansas`. But every string occurs only once, so `Item(0) = Colorado, Item(1) = Colorado` is not possible.

What I try to get is an array with the shortversions of the statenames

Example:
Starting `Array: Item(0) = Colorado, Item(1) = Arkansas`

New Array: `Item(0) = Col, Item(1) = Ark`

So, I need to store information as follows:

```
|Shortversion| Fullversion |
|:-----------|------------:|
| Col        |    Colorado |   
| Ark        |    Arkansas | 
| Uth        |        Utah |
```

So I was looking for a possibiltiy to store the information and get the full state names into another array.

I accomplished that by creating a datatable with the information. For each arrayelement I could find the shorthand version and return the fullname. But that is not a 'performance-oriented' solution. Could anyone help me finding a solution that has a better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that is not a 'performance-oriented' solution

You could use a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var states = new Dictionary<string, string>();
states.Add("Colorado", "Col");
// ...

string abbreviation = states["Colorado"]; // Col
```

In this example the key is the full name and the value is the short-version. Note that the keys must be unique, but that should be the case since you've mentioned that "every string occurs only once".

VB.NET:

```
Dim states As New Dictionary(Of string, string)
states.Add("Colorado", "Col")

Dim abbreviation As String = states("Colorado")
```

Comment: but what if one need to have same shortversion for two fullversion, dictionary will not allow it?

Comment: @CodingDefined: what's the problem? `states.Values` can contain dulicates.

Comment: @TimSchmelter According to `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx` if you use same key for two values you will get `ArgumentException : An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: @CodingDefined: the key is not the short-version but the value. The key(full-name of state) is unique as stated by OP.